# I can't save files and data using guest session

Tags: system, guest-session

I have a problem saving my files and all data created as shown in the following image. How do I save my files?

[image]

Comment: Mount an external device as suggested and copy your files to that.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a problem. This is just usual behaviour of the guest session. You need to use standard user account instead of guest to solve this "problem". This is different question, but if you want to make a customisation of the guest session - please look at [**this manual**](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1558808).